# Is it possible to use the dropdown element in Inquist with no default response?

Tags: inquisit

I have a demographic item in Inquisit where participants indicate their response using a dropdown menu.

However, at the moment it default to showing the first response. Thus, if a participant skipped the question, their response would be recorded as the default. I want to require participants to make an active choice.

**Is there a way of using the `dropdown` element so that there is no default response?**

See the example code below followed by a sample screen shot.

```
<surveypage age>/ questions=[1=age] / showquestionnumbers = false </surveypage>
<dropdown age>
/ caption="Age in years:"
/ options=("18 to 25", "26 to 30", "31 to 40", "41 to 50", "51 and over")
/ required=true
</dropdown>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to combine the `validresponse` attribute with the `options` attribute.

1. Add an empty string or some other descriptive text (e.g., "select option") to the start of the list of options.
2. copy the set of responses in the `validresponse` attribute but remove the empty string.

For example:

```
<surveypage age>/ questions=[1=age] / showquestionnumbers = false </surveypage>
<dropdown age>
/ caption="Age in years:"
/ options=("", "18 to 25", "26 to 30", "31 to 40", "41 to 50", "51 and over")
/ validresponse=("18 to 25", "26 to 30", "31 to 40", "41 to 50", "51 and over")
/ required=true
</dropdown>
```

The screen will default to this:

[image]

and by using the `required=true` option, participants are not able to skip an item. The question will be displayed in red if participants try to skip.

[image]